# SQL select between 2 values price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a value of 15.

I then have a database which contains different ranks for the player.

They have the following information in my ranks table:

```
Level       CountFrom     CountTo
Level 1       0              9
Level 2       10             19
Level 3       20             29
```

How can i pull the level out in a sql command?

I.e i have:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ranks
WHERE `CountTo` <= '15'
```

This will pull Level 1 and Level 2 as result.

The only way i can think of is to then OrderBy CountTo DESC and limit the result to 1.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CountFrom` in the query as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM ranks
WHERE CountFrom <= 15 AND CountTo >= 15
```

- Level 1 will be excluded because its `CountTo`(9) value makes `CountTo >= 15` false.
- Level 2 will be included because its `CountFrom`(10) is true for  `CountFrom <= 15` and its `CountTo`(19) is true for `CountTo >= 15`.
- Level 3 will be excluded because its `CountFrom`(20) values makes `CountFrom <= 15` false.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BETWEEN

```
SELECT *
FROM `ranks
WHERE '15' between `CountTFrom` and `CountTo`
```